# Переделать массив при помощи reduce

Tags: javascript

Приходит такой массив

(можно переделать при помощи `map`, желательно самый оптимальный способ)

```
const arr = [
          {id: null, status: true, comment: ''},
          {id: null, status: true, comment: ''},
          {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
          {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
          {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
          {id: 2, status: true, comment: ''},
        ]
```

Необходимо переделать в **такой**:

```
const result = [
          {id: null, arr: [
              {id: null, status: true, comment: ''},
              {id: null, status: true, comment: ''},
            ]},
          {id: 1, arr: [
              {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
              {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
              {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
            ]},
          {id: 2, arr: [
              {id: 2, status: true, comment: ''},
            ]}
        ]
```

я сделал так и было не правильно в чем была моя ошибка?

```
result.reduce((previousValue: any[], currentValue) => {
          if (previousValue.length > 0) {
             return previousValue.map(el => {
              if (el.id === currentValue.id ) {
                return ({id: el.id, count: el.count + 1})
              } else {
                return ( {id: el.id, count: 1})
              }
            })
          } else {
            return ([ ...previousValue, {applicationId: currentValue.id ,
              count: (previousValue[currentValue.id] || 0) + 1 }])
          }
        }, [])
```

Comment: Так преступайте же скорее

Comment: На stackOverflow не принято задавать вопросы в формате "напишите мне решение", обычно вы прикладываете свои наброски, а вам уже отвечают, что можно подправить, чтоб оно работало

Comment: Вообще удивительно, ведь после преобразования массива, с ним же что-то еще делать нужно? Или это будет следующий вопрос на SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {id: null, status: true, comment: ''},
  {id: null, status: true, comment: ''},
  {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
  {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
  {id: 1, status: true, comment: ''},
  {id: 2, status: true, comment: ''},
];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    let idx = acc.findIndex(e => e.id === cur.id);
    if (idx !== -1) acc[idx].arr.push(cur);
    else acc.push({ id: cur.id, arr: [cur] });
    return acc;
  }, [])
);
```